# Pass URL on an iframe based on checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Sorry I am very bad at JavaScript and I'm just starting to learn it. I have this scenario: I want to pass an URL to my iframe, so how can I create a script out of it?

```js
<script>
  /* Pseudocode 
  
   if var variable1 is true then pass url to iframe with variable1 as value
   
   else if var variable2 is true then pass url to iframe with variable2 as value
   
   else let the default url
  
  */

</script>
Hope someone can know this.

Thank you!
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="(variable1)"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="(variable2)"> 

<iframe id="javascriptID" src="(variable(1or2)">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use radio buttons instead and then do this:

```
HTTPSNow
<input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="https://www.httpsnow.org/" onclick="setURL(this.value)"/> 
<br/>
Example.com
<input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="https://www.example.com/" onclick="setURL(this.value)"/> 
<br/>
<iframe id="javascriptID" src="" width="500px" height="500px">
</iframe>

function setURL(thelink){
    javascriptID.src=thelink;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xLkcjv0d/1/)

Comment: thanks bro.. what will be the value instead the src?

Comment: You mean, the `src` of the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use checkbox, you can use this - with jQuery:

```
$("input[name=vehicle]").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        // do some thing here
    }
})
```

But i think it's not a good idea cause checkbox isn't unique.